# Is necessary to check and verify Google Play Services when using Google Mobile Ads?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I have a simple question. I've developed an Android app that uses AdMob SDK, and now i want to migrate to Google Play Services to use Google Mobile Ads from it.

I've integrate Play services library, but my question is:

Do i have to check and verify if Play Services is installed on user devices and what version, or it is not necessary when using with the Mobile Ads SDK function from Play Services??

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Play Services with AdMob. Check availability?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275325/google-play-services-with-admob-check-availability)

Comment: Sorry @donfuxx, i was looking for an answer in other questions but i didn't find this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you don´t need to check for [Google Play services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/ads.html) to use the Mobile Ads APIs. when you create your app the .jar is already included.

The Google Play services library supports even devices that don't have the Google Play store.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download) say this:

> See the setup instructions and reference docs for details on setting up Google Play services.
>   The Google Play services library supports even devices that don't have the Google Play store. To update such devices, download and bundle the latest Google Play services SDK; then relaunch your apps to propagate updates to your users. Devices that do have the Google Play store are automatically updated to the latest version.
>   The Google Play services library does support publisher IDs from the legacy AdMob console, and is compatible with existing mediation adapters.