# GooglePlayServicesUtil cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-play-services

Recent updation to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0` results in this error. This does not happen when `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0` is used, but it bloats the apk size significantly. Also to implement in-app billing, it is needed to check whether Google Play services are installed or not before starting a purchase.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: This class is included in `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0` and `play-services-ads` does not depend on it. Meaning you don't need it. Seems like ads don't need Google Play services installed.

Comment: But how do I check if play services are installed then?

Comment: You [don't have to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27195547/1676363) - it works whether it is there or not.

Comment: I know that ads work on devices without Play services, but since each result in onActivityResult is passed to iabHelper.handleActivityResult(), this would cause a NullPointerException. Isn't there a workaround for this rather than using try catch?

Comment: What are you talking about? How is this related to the question? Where's the code? What's a iabHelper?

Comment: IabHelper is a helper class for implementing in-app billing. I forgot to mention this in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Google Play Services library in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081598/import-google-play-services-library-in-android-studio)

Comment: I faced same problem, but solved using this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42063112/4531507

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do in order to use `GooglePlayServicesUtil` is include the following dependency in your build.gradle:

**compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0'**

Here you can see all the individual Play Services dependencies that you can pick from:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem but in my case i didn't added any other dependency even my problem solved by just changing the position of `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in the **build.gradle(Modile: app)** file.

Line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

was written at the last in the gradle file. Remove this from here and add it to the top, below the line `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
Like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and sync now. Problem solved.